# Missing SetToken and SetTokenCookie on JsonServiceClient from TypeScript

Tags: servicestack

We are having trouble assigning the BearerToken when calling ServiceStack using JsonServiceClient from TypeScript.  The SetCookie and SetCookieToken methods appear to be missing as described in this question:

[ServiceStack Javascript JsonServiceClient missing properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568936/servicestack-javascript-jsonserviceclient-missing-properties)

We tried the solution described there:

```
this.client.headers.append("Authorization" , "Bearer " + jwtToken);
```

But when we try this we get an HTTP 400: Bad Request

How can we use the the JsonServiceClient from JavaScript with our BearerToken?

Comment: Can you post the full HTTP Response Headers? (e.g via Fiddler or Chrome WebInspector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just added an explicit [setBearerToken() API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/commit/5e8cd2fa25f174c00fcc01618271f212ef109e88) (in v0.0.28) that adds the Bearer Token HTTP Header:

```
setBearerToken(token:string): void {
    this.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
}
```

And confirms that it works in this [node/browser compatible test](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/commit/9c86373b79ff14d8e4a502ca4ca838270c645799):

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://test.servicestack.net");
client.setBearerToken(jwtToken);
var success = await client.post(new Authenticate());
```

Your issue is unrelated to JWT. You should check your HTTP Response Headers to find out more about. A **400** Response is a Bad Request Exception, you would get a **401** Unauthorized response for Unauthorized exceptions.

#### Token Cookie vs Bearer Token

Also note that a `setTokenCookie()` which passes the JWT Token in the `ss=jwt` Cookie is unrelated to the Bearer Token which is added to the `Authorization` HTTP Request Header.

If your JWT is configured correctly when you authenticate via a different auth provider, e.g:

```
var request = new Authenticate();
request.provider = "credentials";
request.userName = userName;
request.password = password;
var authResponse = await client.post(request);
var jwtToken = authResponse.bearerToken;
```

The JWT Token will be populated in `authResponse.bearerToken` which you can use with `client.setBearerToken()` to add the the HTTP Request Header. After your authenticated you can also go to `/auth` to see the JWT BearerToken.

If the `bearerToken` is not populated then JWT Provider isn't populating it for that request. If you're not using `https` you need to ensure [RequireSecureConnection=false](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#requiresecureconnection) to allow it to work over http.

If you prefer you can instead tell ServiceStack you want to use JWT Cookie instead which you can specify when you authenticate with:

```
var request = new Authenticate();
request.useTokenCookie = true;
```

In which case instead of returning it in `bearerToken` the JWT Token is populated in the `ss=tok` HttpOnly Cookie which JavaScript can't access directly, but will be transparently be sent with each future ServiceClient requests.

Comment: Thanks for the great support as usual @mythz.   Once we examined the return headers in more detail as you suggested and found the Exception thrown, we were able to trace the problem to the "CreatedAt" payload in the JWT being in a format ServiceStack didn't expect (string vs. Unix time). The exception came from the PopulateFromMap method in the UserAuthExtension.  Adding the helper method is also useful and makes for a more consistent experience across the different platforms the JsonServiceClient is available on.